# Android fragments getArguments returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm getting null from the args in MyListFragment,
cant figure out why.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get a location from a Map
and replace the old fragment with a new one which has updated location,

MyListFragmnet is a "default" fragment in the NavigationDrawerActivity

//MyListFragment.java

```
public static MyListFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    return newInstance(args);
}

public static MyListFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
    MyListFragment fragment = new MyListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public MyListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    searchQuery = args.getString(SEARCH_QUERY_ARG, ""); //NULL ERROR!!
    final MyLocation checkLocation = (MyLocation) args.getSerializable(LOCATION_ARG);

    if (!searchQuery.isEmpty()) {
        activity.setTitle("\""+searchQuery+"\"");
    }
    setLocation(checkLocation);
```

............

```
private void setLocation(final MyLocation checkLocation) {
        if (checkLocation != null) {
            // If no location is set and there is a check
            location = new Location("");
            location.setLatitude(checkLocation.latitude);
            location.setLongitude(checkLocation.longitude);
        } else {
            // If no location was provided, get the current one
            location = LocationHelper.getInstance().getLocation(context);
        }
    }
```

//NavigationDrawerActivity.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private NavigationView navLayout;

    //Location
    private MyLocation checkLocation;
    private boolean active;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_navigation);
        setupReferences();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        try {
            assert actionBar != null;
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.subtitle));
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navLayout= (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navLayout);
        navLayout.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        active = false;
        checkLocation = (MyLocation) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MyListFragment.LOCATION_ARG);
        handleIntent(getIntent());

        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MyListFragment());
        tx.commit();

    }
    @Override
    public  boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (active) {
            // Only handles the Intent again if the Activity was already active
            handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        super.startActivity(intent);

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            intent.putExtra(MyListFragment.LOCATION_ARG, checkLocation);
        }

        active = true;
    }
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            args.putString(MyListFragment.SEARCH_QUERY_ARG, searchQuery);
            args.putSerializable(MyListFragment.LOCATION_ARG, checkLocation);
        } else if (MyListFragment.ACTION_CHECK.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            checkLocation = (MyLocation) intent.getSerializableExtra(LocationActivity.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            args.putSerializable(MyListFragment.LOCATION_ARG, checkLocation);
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, MyListFragment.newInstance(args)).commit();
    }

}
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `MyListFragment.newInstance()` but simply calling `new MyListFragment()`

this line

```
  tx.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MyListFragment());
```

should be

```
 tx.replace(R.id.frameLayout, MyListFragment.newInstance());
```

Comment: Blackbelt: probably `MyListFragment.newInstance()` method still cause issue because there is not key available with SEARCH_QUERY_ARG name

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, not it is not. `args.getString(SEARCH_QUERY_ARG, ""); ` is falling back on an empty string, which is not null.

Comment: @Blackbelt: yes. agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
...
tx.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MyListFragment());
...
```

Not passing any bundle when creating object of `MyListFragment` Fragment.

Do it by calling `newInstance(Bundle args)` static method for getting Fragment object.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(SEARCH_QUERY_ARG, "data_here"); 
 ...
 tx.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MyListFragment.newInstance(bundle));
 ...
```